# Closing Winform MenuStrip when mouse leaves the container

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, menuitem, mouseleave

I´m have been dealing with this issue all day. I have a menustrip with several menu items.
Each item, also have many items. Now, if I click the parent menu item, a container(similar to contextmenu) stays opened until I click somewhere else.

[image]

In the image example, "Clientes" will be the parent item, and there its the "container" with their child menu items.

What I wanted to do, is to close that "container" when the mouse leaves the parent item or the container area. I dont want to have to click in any other part of the form to close it. When I say that, its because I´m actually using WPF buttons and I need to do it this way.

I need help here, hope somebody can give me some advice.

I tried to use the MouseLeave event of the parents items ("Clientes", etc.) and there did:

```
private void clientesToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clientesToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Close();
    }
```

This works, but obviously, it closes the parent and also the container, when the mouse leaves menuitem "Clientes". I need a way to know if the mouse is over the parent menuitem or over one of their childs so as to close it if I know that the mouse is somewhere else.

Hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: What control are you using? `MenuStrip`?

Comment: @OscarMederos Yes. That one.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by handling events of clientesToolStripMenuItem itself. When the mouse enters your clients main-menu rectangle, just show your container and hide it when it leaves this rectangle. Assuming picContainer is your rectangle, you may do something like this:

```
private void clientToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picContainer.Location = clientToolStripMenuItem.ContentRectangle.Location;
    picContainer.Show();
}

private void clientToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.picContainer.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I dont understand too much your solution. As you said, picContainer will be my rectangle. How can I create that? Also, I notice you hide it when the mouse leaves clientToolStripMenuItem, what I need is to hide/close when it leaves any of the items of the container. Just in case, I call container to the contentrectangle of an item with all it childs menu items. Hope you can explain me a little more please. Thank you again!

Comment: In your question, you said about "a container(similar to contextmenu)". In the image, this container is having menu items like "Nuevo cliente", etc. right? The picContainer in my example is the equivalent of that. Secondly, why would you hide/close when it leaves any of the items of the container, its already hidden. You want to show it only when the mouse moves into the area of this particular Clientes menu, right ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. Thanks for trying to help, but I dont need an answer anymore. I just implemented the menu in another way.